# Cache memory occupied in RHEL

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am running my app servers (one instance each of Karaf, Tomcat, Mongo and Zookeeper) in a RHEL environment and often see that (using free -m) of my total 12GB RAM almost 8GM is shown as cached. The app slows down as well. Why is this happening. I even tried to stop all of these services gracefully until i have only the Linux OS alone running on my box. Even then the cache is not freed. I have to manually free it to bring it down.

Why is the cache being accumulated like this and Does it have something to do with my application? Is it a good practise to run a chron job like this just to free the cache?

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the "cache" from the last column here:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3954       3580        374          0          1       1448
```

then there is no reason to clear it. This cache is absolutely harmless, it retains (caches) for example previously opened files for faster access. When more memory is needed, this cache is automatically cleared. There is no reason why this cache would slow down any apps.

Update: Some apps store temporary files in memory, /dev/shm is usually a place for this, but you can check these on your system using:

```
$ mount|grep tmpfs
```

These files also show up in the cached column, but this data is not harmless in the sense that it cannot be dropped when more free memory is needed.

Comment: free -m gives me the following values :

total-7767, used-7638, free-128, shared-0, buffers-2, cached-4949.

Only 128MB is free and nearly 4.5GB is in cache and they dont get cleared even if i execute "sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" as root. But the same command removes my cache if i stop one of the process (mongodb) running on the server.

What does this implicate?

Comment: I added some more info to my response. I'm not familiar with mongodb but probably it uses temp files just like I said in my updated response. If so, you can try to find these files in the directories listed by the command above and recreate the directory containing the temp files on a hard disk partition. For example if mongodb would put it's temp files in /dev/shm/mongodb, then you could mount a small partition into that dir while mongodb is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache.

```
#sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```